# Building Hadoop on windows 7, can't copy files

Tags: windows, hadoop

Trying to install hadoop 2.7.1 on windows, it has been a nightmare but finally gotten to the part where the distribution part is failing to build. Can't seem to work out why it won't copy the files, the stack trace is below: (also is it a permissions error?)

```
main:
Property "@" has not been set
Property "@" has not been set
     [exec] Current OS is Windows 7
     [exec] Executing 'sh' with arguments:
     [exec] './dist-layout-stitching.sh'
     [exec]
     [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
     [exec] not part of the command.
Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'sh' with arguments:
'./dist-layout-stitching.sh'

The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.
     [exec]
     [exec] Current directory /cygdrive/d/Hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1-src/hadoop-dist/target
     [exec]
     [exec] $ rm -rf hadoop-2.7.1
     [exec] $ mkdir hadoop-2.7.1
     [exec] $ cd hadoop-2.7.1
     [exec] $ cp /cygdrive/d/Hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1-src/LICENSE.txt .
     [exec] $ cp /cygdrive/d/Hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1-src/NOTICE.txt .
     [exec] $ cp /cygdrive/d/Hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1-src/README.txt .
     [exec] $ cp -r /cygdrive/d/Hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/hadoop-common-2.7.1/bin /cygdrive/d/Hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/hadoop-common-2.7.1/etc /cygdrive/d/Hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/hadoop-common-2.7.1/libexec /cygdrive/d/Hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/hadoop-common-2.7.1/sbin /cygdrive/d/Hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/target/hadoop-common-2.7.1/share .
     [exec] $ cp -r /cygdrive/d/Hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1-src/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-nfs/target/hadoop-nfs-2.7.1/share .
     [exec] $ cp -r /cygdrive/d/Hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/target/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.1/* .
     [exec]
     [exec] Failed!
     [exec]
     [exec] cp: cannot stat ‘/cygdrive/d/Hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1-src/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/target/hadoop-hdfs-2.7.1/*’: No such file or directory
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.247 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-09T12:39:00+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 35M/212M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (dist) on project hadoop-dist: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec dir="D:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1-src\hadoop-dist\target" executable="sh" failonerror="true">... @ 38:96 in D:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1-src\hadoop-dist\target\antrun\build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (dist) on project hadoop-dist: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
around Ant part ...<exec dir="D:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1-src\hadoop-dist\target" executable="sh" failonerror="true">... @ 38:96 in D:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1-src\hadoop-dist\target\antrun\build-main.xml
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned: 1
around Ant part ...<exec dir="D:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1-src\hadoop-dist\target" executable="sh" failonerror="true">... @ 38:96 in D:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1-src\hadoop-dist\target\antrun\build-main.xml
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: D:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1-src\hadoop-dist\target\antrun\build-main.xml:38: exec returned: 1
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:646)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:327)
        ... 21 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed cygwin from the path temporarily, rebuilt. It worked